# Splash pages in web design: How do you maintain searchability?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Everyone here who might have an ounce of understanding as to how Googlebot works might clearly see that splash pages can hurt a website's SEO performance.

However, I happen to be dealing with the rather unfortunate case of having to implement a splash page for one of my clients. How do you do it without threatening my client's rankings? I know it can be done, as some other major label artist sites (eg, katyperry.com, ladygaga.com) seem to get away with it.

--Dany.

Answer (score 1):

make the splash page as a javascript/css overlay (like lightbox) .. the client won't realize the difference as he seems to be an ***** anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your splash screen has a link to the 'real' home page then the spider should follow it. And the better content on the 'real' home page should boost it above the splash in the rankings.

Comment: This is a good reason why 'splash pages' are (generally) frowned upon. They become superfluous in a search engine environment because the crawler/robot will find your 'acutal' home page far richer with content goodness and promote it over the splash.

Of course, for being the top page the 'splash page' will also get a boost from the good content of lower pages.

Comment: @Crashdown, while in most cases I would agree that splash pages should be avoided for that very reason, I also believe they should be evaluated for their merits on a case-by-case basis. In my specific case, I am dealing with a musical artist's website whose content ( consisting of photos, places to get tickets, and perhaps a bio) wouldn't be of terribly great importance anyway, relative to that of a website that generates its livelihood from its content. The core goal of this website, in my case, is not the website itself and it gives me reason to consider a splash page.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the robot from the HTTP request header and suppress the splash page for the bot. Most common search engine bots have their host address listed on the web.

Comment: While this works, it's risky; search engines frown on websites altering behavior for their crawlers.

Comment: I agree with @coreyward. Another alternative would be to have the splash page separate with a HTTP reload or javascript to jump to the content page and use a robots.txt file to get the robots to skip the splash page.

Comment: do your suggestions imply that my splash page have a temporal delay on it before it refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a helpful thread for you on Google Webmaster forum: [Did splash page create indexing problems?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=618f89bdb6041dde&hl=en)

Comment: having read this, I'm a little lost as to what the recommendation for splash pages is here. Is it implying that I should use a 301 redirect somehow to my main index?

Comment: Don't know what the actionable take away is, but they do seem to be dealing with your concern there... And, the "Top Contributor Webmaster Help Bionic" doesn't seem at all worried about the other guy's splash page affecting his rank (provided that everything else is on the up-and-up.) Sorry if that isn't very helpful!